# displaying information in a jQuery popup div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that has multiple areas that, when clicked, will show a popup div with information inside.  The popup works, and actually displays the information inside, however, it's the information for all of the clickable areas, not specific to the clicked area.  My question is, how do I get the popup to show the specific info for the area clicked?

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
    <div class="example"><img src="images/army.jpg" /><div class="description"><p>Active Duty</p></div></div>
    <div class="example"><img src="images/reserve.jpg" /><div class="description"><p>Reserves</p></div></div>
    <div class="example"><img src="images/gsu.png" /><div class="description"><p>Georgia Southern</p></div></div>
    <div class="example"><img src="images/twc.png" /><div class="description"><p>The Weather Chanel</p></div></div>
    <div class="example"><img src="images/fsi.jpg" /><div class="description"><p>FlightSafety International</p></div></div>
    <div class="example"><img src="images/freelance.jpg" /><div class="description"><p>Freelance</p></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapper').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#wrapper').append('<div id="popup"><p class="close">X</p></div>');
    $('.example').append('<p>Click here to read about my experience<p>');
    $('#content').find('.description').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).find('p').text();
    $('#popup').append(text);
    })

    $('.example p').on('click', function(){
    $('#popup, #mask').show();
    })

    $('.close, #mask').click(function(){
    $('#popup, #mask').hide();
    })
})
```

Here's my Pen for a visual reference.  http://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/dCiIE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove these lines:

```
$('#content').find('.description').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).find('p').text();
    $('#popup').append(text);
});
```

Then change your click:

```
$('.example p').on('click', function(){
    $('#popup').text($(this).prev('.description').text());
    $('#popup, #mask').show();
})
```

And it should work

Answer (score 0):

Since there's only one popup, you'll need to add the content only on when you click that particular `<p>` element. Try:

```
$('.example p').on('click', function(){
    var text = $(this).prev('.description').find('p').text();
    $('#popup').html(text);
    $('#popup, #mask').show();
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/herCJ